# How I can detect first app lauch in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I work on a Flutter mobile app and I want to detect the first app launch to show a little tutorial to the user. I have tests the Shared-Preferences Module But when If I start the app for the first time The console tells me the key is not recognized, I think it's normal because this key does exist! There is another method for checking that?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **shared preferences** to store value that indicate if user has ever been in this page or not

like this

```
try {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  splash = sharedPreferences.getString("SPLASH_DONE");
} catch (e) {
  print("this is first time");
}

if (splash == null) {
  page = AppSplashScreen();
} else {
  page = LoginPage();
}
```

and after completing your first time operation call

```
sharedPreferences.setString("SPLASH_DONE", "DONE");
```

Comment: glad to hear that !